# How to use variable in php path

Tags: php, variables, upload

Hello Im working on my school project but I have a problem my english isnt that to good so I will try my best to explaine it to you.

I am using a php script to upload files I have tested it with a static path everything worked $file_destination ="/uploads/.$file_name_new";

but when I change it to
$file_destination ="/uploads/$gebruiker/.$file_name_new"; it doenst work I have also tried it with '/' what am I doing wrong???

---

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('Connections/RemoteServer.php');

$gebruiker = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $file= $_FILES['file'];

    //eigenschappen bestand

    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    //file extensie
    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

     //"/users".$username."/"; test!!!!!

    $allowed = array('txt', 'pdf', 'docx');

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
        if($file_error === 0){
            if($file_size <= 5000000)  {

                $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) .'.'. $file_ext;
                $file_destination ="/uploads/$gebruiker/.$file_name_new";
                if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)){


                echo($file_name ." Is met succes Geupload" );


                }


            }
        }

    }

}



?>
```

![root structure][1]
deadline tommorow :(

Comment: can you see hidden files on your server as you have a dot at the beginning of your file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the variable outside of the string:

```
$file_destination = "uploads/".$gebruiker."/".$file_name_new;
```

And the directory has to exist. You can use

```
mkdir("uploads/".$gebruiker);
$file_destination = "uploads/".$gebruiker."/".$file_name_new;
```

Comment: thx for your help but i tried that already I get this error :Warning: move_uploaded_file(/uploads/Marvin/54935d060d3904.22699500.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\CSMS_VERSIE2.0\uploadfile.php on line 31//// But I already made the map: Marvin

Comment: Ah okay. So the folder doesn't exist. One second, I'll edit it in

Comment: no the folder exist I have made these folders uploads/Marvin inside ?

Comment: Can you please post your directory structure in your question

Comment: screenshot uploaded I appreciate the help (y)

Comment: @marrie are you sure that $_SESSION['MM_Username'] is set and named Marvin? –  baao 1 min ago